# Resolving dependencies without a dependency injection container

Tags: php, testing, dependency-injection

I have a project in plain PHP and there is a class which is dependent on external library.

I don't feel like passing it to constructor everywhere is a good idea (it's called mainly in tests, but the users of the package will have to pass it to constructor).

I don't have any DI containers and don't think I should have because the project is a small package and will only have a few classes.

So I've come up with this approach and was wondering if there any consequences or drawbacks of this approach or if there any other solution to this?

```php
    protected $client;

    /**
     * @param Client|null $client
     */
    public function __construct(Client $client = null)
    {
        $this->client = $client ?? new Client();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any major issue with that. Your class simply falls back to a default `Client` implementation if one isn't injected into it, but since you're not enforcing it, it retains the appropriate flexibility/testability.

I would however go a bit further and implement [Dependency Inversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62539/what-is-the-dependency-inversion-principle-and-why-is-it-important):

```
interface IClient  // maybe find a slightly more suitable name for it
{
  // define Client's public interface methods here
}
```

Change your Client class to implement it:

```
class Client implements IClient 
{
  // ...
}
```

Then change the constructor to this:

```
public function __construct(IClient $client = null)
{
  $this->client = $client ?? new Client();
}
```

This way your class doesn't even depend on any implementation at all. It just happens to default to `Client` if it isn't explicitly given one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it might work for you?

```
protected $client;

public function __construct(Client $client = null)
{
   this->client = isset($client) ?? new Client();
}
```