# OOP design pattern to use project specific subclass in shared library

Tags: oop, design-patterns

**TL;DR** A shared library implements some class which is used within the library itself and within the projects which use the library. The project inherits the class to add project specific code. **Is there some design pattern / best practice to use this project specific subclass within the library as well?**

---

**Details:**

I have created a library (Swift package) with code and classes I use in multiple iOS app projects.

For example the `ThemeManager` class handles styling and layout of different controls:

```
// In Shared Package
public class ThemeManager {
    public class func styleLabel(_ label: UILabel) {
        // Apply default style to label
    }
}

public class SharedViewController: UIViewController {
    func applyStyle() {
        ThemeManager.styleLabel(someLabel)
    }
}
```

A project using the package might now extend the `ThemeManager` to apply its own, project specific styles.

```
// In Project
public class ProjectThemeManager: ThemeManager {
    override public class func styleLabel(_ label: UILabel) {
        // Apply project style to label
    }
}
```

If the `SharedViewController` is used within the project, it will still style `someLable` with the default style defined in `ThemeManager` instead of using the `ProjectThemeManager`.

Of course there are different ways of solving this. For example `SharedViewController` could simple use a `var themeManager: ThemeManager` instead, which has to be set to the desired type within the project. However, this would be very cumbersome if `ThemeManager` is not used at one place but by many, many different classes.

Another solution would be to use some central instance which has to be configured by the project and the library codes fetches the correct types / instances from there.

**So, the question is not if this can be solved, but if there is an existing OOP design pattern or best practice that addresses this kind of problem.**

Comment: You can define a `ThemeManagerFactory` in the lib which by default will create a standard `ThemeManagerFactory`, but also allows setting a specific factory (at startup?) to use the manager created by that. Otherwise, dependency injection, but that depends on language and framework.

Answer (score 0):

> Of course there are different ways of solving this. For example `SharedViewController` could simple use a var `themeManager: ThemeManager` instead, which has to be set to the desired type within the project.

I'd use Constructor Injection for this. I've never written Swift code, and I would probably botch the syntax if I tried, so I hope this C#(ish) code gets the point across:

```
public class SharedViewController : UIViewController
{
    private readonly ThemeManager themeManager;

    public SharedViewController(ThemeManager themeManager)
    {
        this.themeManager = themeManager;
    }

    public void ApplyStyle()
    {
        themeManager.styleLabel(someLabel); // Use the injected class field
    }
}
```

This is essentially a variation of the [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

> However, this would be very cumbersome if `ThemeManager` is not used at one place but by many, many different classes.

This is a problem that can be solved in various ways: The simplest solution may be the [Facade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), passing around some sort of accessor that can be overridden by the library consumer. See [DI-Friendly Library](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library) and [DI-Friendly Framework](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework) for detailed suggestions.

> Another solution would be to use some central instance which has to be configured by the project and the library codes fetches the correct types / instances from there.

I wouldn't recommend taking that route, since this implies static mutable state AKA a *global variable*. If I understand the implied intent correctly, this describes the Service Locator (anti-)pattern, which (among many other problems) [violates encapsulation](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/10/26/service-locator-violates-encapsulation).

Answer (score -1):

> A project using the package might now extend the ThemeManager to apply its own, project specific styles.
> If the SharedViewController is used within the project, it will still style someLable with the default style defined in ThemeManager instead of using the ProjectThemeManager.

It looks like you need to apply various styles based on some conditions. If we call different styles like strategy, then we can make a conclusion that it is necessary to apply a strategy of styling which depends on some reasons.

So, It is possible to  apply [Strategy](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy) pattern here. It is also enhances [separation of concerns](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32581/how-do-you-explain-separation-of-concerns-to-others).  What I mean is one class has just one goal.

Let's imagine we have some various `LabelStyles` that should be called based on type. Let me show a code snippet via C#.

So code of label styles would look like this:

```
enum LabelStyleType
{
    ThemeManager, ProjectThemeManager
}
```

And abstaction of LabelStyle would look like this:

```
public abstract class LabelStyleBase
{
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public abstract string Get();
}
```

and concrete implementations would like this:

```
public class ThemeManagerStyle : LabelStyleBase
{
    public override string Get() => 
        "I am ThemeManagerStyle. Object created: " + StartDateTime.ToString();
}

public class ProjectThemeManagerStyle : LabelStyleBase
{
    public override string Get() => 
        "I am ProjectThemeManagerStyle. Object created: " 
        + StartDateTime.ToString();
}
```

And then `LabelStyleFactory` would look like this:

```
public class LabelStyleFactory
{
    private Dictionary<LabelStyleType, LabelStyleBase> _labelStyleByType;

    public LabelStyleFactory()
    {
        _labelStyleByType = new Dictionary<LabelStyleType, LabelStyleBase>()
        {
            { LabelStyleType.ThemeManager, new ThemeManagerStyle() },
            { LabelStyleType.ProjectThemeManager, new ProjectThemeManagerStyle() }
        };
    }

    public LabelStyleBase GetInstance(LabelStyleType userInput) => 
        _labelStyleByType[userInput];
}
```

And then you can call your LabelStyle where it is necessary like this:

```
string GetLabelStyleByUserInput(LabelStyleType labelStyleType)
{
    LabelStyleFactory labelStyleFactory = new LabelStyleFactory();
    LabelStyleBase labelStyle = labelStyleFactory.GetInstance(labelStyleType);
    return labelStyle.Get();
}
```

It can be seen that if you add new LabelStyle, you will add it to `LabelStyleFactory` class and it complies with Single Responsibility Principle and Open closed principle

### UPDATE:

> LabelStyleFactory violates the Open/Closed Principle: every additional style requires updating
> LabelStyleType leaving the enum open for modification

I do not think that Open Closed Principle should be applied to `enum` because `enum` is not a class and it is just an enumeration of type of objects like SMS, Email, WhatsApp. What if world has tomorrow new way to communicate? We would not edit `enum` because it is a violation of OCP? I would apply OCP to `SharedViewController`. And now it is closed for modification and opened for extension. If tomorrow new style is added, then what we want to edit would be just `enum` and `LabelStyleFactory`. And we have just one reason to edit a class and an enum abnd it complies with [Single Responsibility Principle explained Robert C. Martin (Uncle Bob)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17100/clarify-the-single-responsibility-principle).

> It further violates the Dependency Inversion Principle by hard-coding concrete dependencies in its constructor.
> I am not sure that the Dependency Inversion Principle is mentioned here. Because [there are no dependencies in its constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62539/what-is-the-dependency-inversion-principle-and-why-is-it-important). Also  it complies with SRP and with “[Encapsulate what varies?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/337413/what-does-it-mean-when-one-says-encapsulate-what-varies)”.
> Moreover, it is an example of a [simple factory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/149207800X) in the chapter about factories.

> And the design isn't really a factory at all, but is an example of the Service Locator anti-pattern described by Mark Seemann.

I'm not sure that you are right and it is not worth downvoting because:

- I do not think that it is a service locator pattern because this great book `Head First Design Pattern` shows and says that it is [an example of simple factory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/149207800X). I know that there is no such a pattern, so I can rename from `LabelStyleFactory` to `LabelStyleStore`
- Mark Seemann's article clearly says [what conditions make Service locator to be antipattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/10/26/service-locator-violates-encapsulation/), however my code avoids violation of encapsulation and my case is clearly shown in the end of this article [Service Locator violates encapsulation](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/10/26/service-locator-violates-encapsulation/):

> As Object-Oriented Software Construction explains, a contract consists of a set of pre- and
> postconditions for interaction. If the client satisfies the preconditions, the object promises to
> satisfy the postconditions.

**And my code has all necessary preconditions**. What I mean is that you need to have `LabelStyleType` to get a concrete instance of `LabelStyleBase`. The code will not work without preconditions. As a result, this code cannot be considered as an anti-pattern according to the article.

But all in all, Service Locator can be considered as [not antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795459/is-servicelocator-an-anti-pattern) and also [Martin Fowler has such an article that Service Locator is not a bad thing.](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator)

Comment: `LabelStyleFactory` violates the Open/Closed Principle: every additional style requires updating `LabelStyleType` leaving the enum open for modification. It further violates the Dependency Inversion Principle by hard-coding concrete dependencies in its constructor. And the design isn't really a factory at all, but is an example of the Service Locator anti-pattern described by Mark Seemann.